# add_shortcode(); is php predefined or only WordPress function?

Tags: php, wordpress

add_shortcode(); is php predefined or only WordPress function? I need to make a plugin for several calculators and each calculator have a separate shortcode. Please help me out community.

Comment: Looking at [php.net](https://www.php.net/) for less than 10 seconds showed me there is no such function in the language itself, so...

Answer (score 0):

add_shortcode functions is defined in wordpress core
"wp-includes/shortcodes.php"
in the above file.